# Sendkey() for textarea

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have the following html code:

```
<div>
   <textarea id="modalContentText"
         data-modal="home.modal"
         ng-model="home.modal.data.text"
         ng-required="true">
   </textarea>
</div>
```

And variation of test codes based on what I have read online so far:

```
//First try
it('Enter text', function () {
   element(by.id('modalContentText')).click();
   element(by.id('modalContentText')).sendKeys('Content 1');
});

//Second try
it('Enter text', function () {
   element(by.id('modalContentText')).clear();
   element(by.id('modalContentText')).sendKeys('Content 1');
});

//Third try
it('Enter text', function () {
   element(by.id('modalContentText')).click();
   element(by.id('modalContentText')).clear();
   element(by.id('modalContentText')).sendKeys('Content 1');
});
```

But none of the test codes is working. First try gives me "UnknownError: cannot focus element". Both second and third try give me "InvalidElementStateError: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it". Does anyone knows how is this done properly? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, the element is not in readonly mode?

Comment: I haven't set anything to readonly mode

Comment: InvalidElementStateError occurs because of these reasons. Like you have tried to click an textarea, which will result in this exception as textarea cant be clicked. clear, sendKeys will automatically move the focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to exception here is problem with element. As it cannot recieve focus and cannot be cleared because of read-only status. You can try use `executeScript` methods in selenium and set value in field using it. e.g.

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.Css("#modalContentText"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", element, newValue);
```